# Lightning component mobile compatibility

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile

Any ideas on how to create a lightning component that is compatible to all mobile devices. For example if I use iPhone 10x or below the lightning component UI should be responsive and compatible.

Thanks.

Comment: Lightning components build with SLDS css are mobile friendly to begin with, have you tried using SLDS grid structure? https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/

Answer (score 2):

Responsive Grid

A responsive grid breaks your page up into a collection of rows, each of which decomposes into a common number of columns. On a large device the row will contain all columns, while on an extra-small device such as a phone, the grid can reflow to display one column per row, stacking the columns vertically instead of laying them out horizontally.

This is achieved via CSS media queries - a media query is essentially CSS that limits its scope based on attributes of the device. For example, consider the following media query:

> .sidebar { display: none; } @media (min-width: 1024px) { .sidebar {
>   display: block; } }

the initial CSS rule mandates that anything with a class of sidebar will be hidden by setting the display attribute to none. The next rule is constrained by a media query and only applies if the minimum width of the device is 1024 pixels. This rule overrides the sidebar style to make it visible by setting the display attribute to block. Thus any user accessing the page on a small device will not see content with the sidebar class, while those accessing from a large device will.

Lightning Design System

on a small device I want each component to span the full width of the device, while on a large device I want the search/about component to appear in a smaller sidebar on the right hand side.

Using the responsive grid, I can keep the same content, but define different column spans based on the device itself.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap"> <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--3-of-4"> ... </div> <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-4"> ... </div> </div>
```

As the grid styles are mobile first, whatever I specify as the default (slds-size—1-of-1) will apply from extra small upwards. My override for medium (slds-slds-medium-size—3-of-4) will apply to that device size and upwards, so covering medium and large devices.

Reference :- [bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2015/10/responsive-design-with-lightning-design.html?m=1](http://for%20more%20information%20click%20here)

Also salesforce mobile app will be supported in android and ios but not in windows.  Browser version are supported in all three.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `$Browser` global value provider that returns information about the hardware and operating system of the browser accessing the application.

Use it like so:

```
<aura:component>
    {!$Browser.isTablet}
    {!$Browser.isPhone}
    {!$Browser.isAndroid}
    {!$Browser.formFactor}
</aura:component>
```

and in controller JS:

```
({
    checkBrowser: function(component) {
        var device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        alert("You are using a " + device);
    }
})
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_browser_value_provider.htm).

Comment: This answer helps us identify the phone/browser, but I think the question is not about identifying the browser but to make it responsive to different mobiledevices/browsers.